# Using finish() to "end" an activity manually: To or Not to?

Tags: java, android

Have a question for Android Developers. I've been in the Udacity Android Beginners course over the last couple of months and had a fellow student tell me I should be calling the `finish()` method on my intents when I move to a new Activity. I googled around and looked at developer documentation to try and discover where he learned about this method and what the documentation says about calling it but I can only find general explanations to how it works and not much in terms of when to call it and why to call it.

I understand what a stack is in memory and he mentioned that its to clear that stack but I've read that Android handles this on its own and we don't need to worry about it. I checked another question here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548258/where-should-we-use-finish-to-end-the-application) which is similar to what I asked but doesn't quite answer the question: Do I need to explicitly call the `finish()` method on my intents or does Android handle this? If I do need to call `finish()`, what are the best practices for calling it? As a reference and in case my question is not clear for some reason here is some sample code from my app and a [link to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/kingdomseed/OfficialImperialBusiness):

```
Intent nextIntent= new Intent(OtherActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
startActivity(nextIntent); 
finish();
```

Comment: I think that finishing activity depends on activities and resources that been used by them , if the activity uses much resources you need to finish it if user navigates to another one , if the user could use the activity for once and may not open it several times you should finish it .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594996/activity-finish-called-but-activity-stays-loaded-in-memory

Comment: This makes sense to me and your link led me to this article which was also helpful: http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html

Now the question is, do I need it in my three / four activity app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `finish()`, android takes your activity out of the activity stack. If you don't call it, the activity remains in the stack and if you press back button on your android phone, the default behavior is that the android will pop back the top activity on the stack. You can of course override the back button functionality. The most common use of calling finish on an activity is when you don't want to comeback to this activity, like for example if you have a splash screen activity. You would want to call finish on it when you move away from it. Other use cases totally depend on application specific navigation hierarchy and performance goals.

Comment: The specific use here as related to this app is: I have a menu screen that takes you to a quiz. After you answer questions on the quiz you move to a results activity. From there you can move back to the main menu.

Comment: @JasonHolt In this case I would probably want to finish the activity so that the user cannot go back to the quiz, rather when they hit back they would go back to the menu.

Comment: @JasonHolt yes in that case just call finish on your Quiz Activity. You wouldn't want to go back to quiz from Results Activity. If that answers your question. Can you accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. You don't have to call `finish()` on each of your `Activity` transitions as Android handles the stack properly. However, you might need the explicit `finish()` call in several places. For example,

- While you are starting an `Activity` by calling `startActivityForResult` and from the `Activity` started, you want to pass the result back to the calling `Activity` using `setResult`. Then you might need `finish()` the `Activity` started after sending the result to the calling `Activity` in some cases.
- When you are opening a `DialogActivity`, you might have some logic on which you want the `DialogActivity` to disappear. Then you call the `finish()` function explicitly.
- A fullscreen `Activity`, might require disabling the `onBackPressed`, as you are going to close the `Activity` using a close button. In that case you need to call the `finish()` method explicitly on pressing the close button in your `Activity`.
- If you intend to close all other `Activity` in the back stack, while starting a specific `Activity`, you don't need to call the `finish()` method either after starting each `Activity` that requires to go to that specific `Activity`. You just have to change the `launchMode` of that specific `Activity` in the manifest file to do so.

  ```
  <activity
      android:name=".ClearBackStackActivity"
      android:label="You want to clear the back stack of activities"
      android:launchMode="singleTask">
  ```

**Update**

> So for clarification, I have a quiz activity that allows you to answer
>   questions. When you submit the quiz you are taken to a results
>   activity. Ideally, would I want to set the quiz activity itself to be
>   cleared after the results are tallied and passed to the results
>   activity? Would that achieve the desired goal and be memory efficient?
>   I don't know if this makes sense what I'm asking here.

As far as I have understood, you want to clear the quiz activity after all answers are submitted and you have moved the user to the result activity. In this specific case, I can suggest you two different ways.

- You might consider having a `ResultActivity` as your launcher. To start the quiz you might consider staring the `QuizActivity` using `startActivityForResult` and then after the answers in the `QuizActivity` are submitted, you are calculating the score and pass the score to the `ResultActivity` again using `setResult` from your `QuizActivity` and then call `finish()` method on your `QuizActivity`. You will be receiving the score passed from `QuizActivity` in the `onActivityResult` function in your `ResultActivity`.
- The other way of doing this is having a `QuizActivity` as launcher which will have the questions and after submitting the answers, the score will be calculated and the `ResultActivity` will be opened with the score earned. I would like to suggest both of the activities to have `launchMode=SingleTask`. By clicking a button in the `ResultActivity` will start another `QuizActivity`.

Comment: So for clarification, I have a quiz activity that allows you to answer questions. When you submit the quiz you are taken to a results activity. Ideally, would I want to set the quiz activity itself to be cleared after the results are tallied and passed to the results activity? Would that achieve the desired goal and be memory efficient? I don't know if this makes sense what I'm asking here.